# Share folder from docker container to host

Tags: docker

Is there a way to share folder from docker container to host?

For example I have tomcat inside docker container and I want it to be visible from the outside.

If I do
volumes:
   - /opt/tomcat:/opt/tomcat

I receive an error in the container:
"No such file or directory /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh"

Comment: Are you using `-v HOST_FOLDER:CONTAINER_FOLDER`? If so it should work... Maybe that is a symlink to something outside of the directory you are mounting?

Comment: It works, but host rewrites the directory contents inside the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Docker allows you to that. That command will mount your host folder in the container, so your files in the container are not visible anymore.

Two options:

1. You can access the container files using [this trick (GitHub issue)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26872#issuecomment-249315020):
   `sudo ls /proc/$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME)/root`. To access them you will need root privileges, or you can use bindfs to match root user with your user name (see the same thread).
2. Create a new volume, copy the files you need to be accessible to there and mount it inside the container, in the right place

Comment: Could you elaborate on `2`, @Salem?